# Query with attribute $all in MongoDB, how can I make a case-insensitive query?

Tags: java, database, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I need to do a query on mongoDB due to I am developing in Java with Spring Boot and MongoDB. I know that this command is for arrays:

```
@Query("{ 'skills' : {$all : ?0}} ")
List<DataCV2> findAllSkillsInCV(ArrayList<String> skillsOfCV);
```

This query let me to find if all fields of the arraylist "skillsOfCV" are in the arraylist called "skills". However, I would like to do the same with a case-insensitive query. For command "regex" there is one option and it is to put "$options: 'i'". Is there any way to achieve this for the $all command?

Comment: You can use Collation for specifying a case-insensitive search using find.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a straightforward way. You can use `$and` instead.

> The $all is equivalent to an $and operation of the specified values

[Reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#equivalent-to--and-operation)